# JavaScript set nested object (tree node) property dynamically

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic, variable-assignment

Let's assume that there's a nested object:

```
const nested = {
    foo: {
        bar: {
            baz: [
                {t1: {id: 1, _value: 1}},
                {t2: {id: 2, _value: 2}}
            ],
            _value: 3
        },
        nuxt: {
            _value: 4
        },
        _value: 5
    }
}
```

How to dynamically set the key of _value to a desired number in a function of a following signature?

By dynamically, I mean to have a function, that accepts a string like `"foo|nuxt"` or `"foo|bar|baz|t{n}|id:1|"`.

**For Instance:**

```
function setValue({path, key, value}, target) {}
```

With a call signature of `setValue({path: "foo|nuxt", key:"_value", value: 100}, nested}`

P.S. There's no issue in parsing a `path`.

Thank you!

Comment: lodash has [`set`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set)

Comment: Thanks for the hint Matt! Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out for vanilla JS, however, this does not work as expected in Svelte.

Thanks everyone.

```
function setValue({path, key, value}, target) {
    let tokens = path.split("|");

    let oPtr = target;

    tokens.map(token => {
        if(oPtr.hasOwnProperty(token)) {
            oPtr = oPtr[token];
        }
    });

    oPtr[key] = value;

}
```